# Increment the value of all elements in a JSON array and display it using Polymer components

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a JSON file (containing an integer array) to which a I send a `<iron-ajax>` request and retrieve the response. I want to process the response (an the integer array) and increment all the values in the integer array by one on a button-click.

Every time I click the button, it should increment the value by 1.

**My element template:**

```
<iron-ajax
         url="/api/time-series/simple-data/4"
         last-response="{{_simpleDataValuesA}}"
         auto>
</iron-ajax>

<h1> /* Where I would like the entire updated array to be shown when I press the BUTTON to increment */
```

**My Polymer definition:**

```
 Polymer({

    is: 'new-page',
    properties: {
        _simpleDataValuesA: {
            type: Object
        },
        _cal: {
            type: Array,
            computed: 'cal_incr(_simpleDataValuesA)'
        }
    },
    cal_incr:function(_simpleDataValuesA){
        var a = this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0];
        a.forEach(function increment(item,index,a) {
            a[index]+=1;
        })
        console.log('array -- >',a);
        console.log('this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0] -- >',this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0]);
        this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0]=a;

        return this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values;
    }
});
```

**My JSON File:**

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "data": {
    "labels": ["acvc","b","a","b","a"],
    "values": [[112,57,53,122,128,120,56]]  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommended steps:

1. Create a `<button>` that has a `click`-handler that modifies the values of `_simpleDataValuesA.data.values`:

   ```
   <button on-click="_incrementValues">Increment</button>
   ```
2. In your script, define that `click`-handler as follows (*Note:* We use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to update each value in the array):

   ```
   _incrementValues: function() {
     var a = this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0];

     // Update the array with incremented values
     this._simpleDataValuesA.data.values[0] = a.map(function(item) {
       return item + 1;
     });

     // Bypass Polymer's dirty-check (in order to notify the
     // data bindings) by assigning the property to an empty
     // object and then itself.
     var copy = this._simpleDataValuesA;
     this._simpleDataValuesA = {};
     this.set('_simpleDataValuesA', copy);
   }
   ```
3. Update your element's `<template>` to display the array values like this:

   ```
   <ul>
     <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_simpleDataValuesA.data.values.0]]">
       <li>[[item]]</li>
     </template>
   </ul>
   ```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNkLvF7gsAuyTWBUCci7?p=preview)

Comment: @AnkitaGavali No problem :)